# OnChildRemoved(Element child) not working on Xamarin.Forms 4.8 version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, layout, removechild

I have created custom layout inherited from `Layout`.

Still, I am using `OnChildRemoved(Element child)` for identifying the child removal process.

After changing Xamarin.Forms 4.8 version, `OnChildRemoved(Element child)` not working, I have changed this method to `OnChildRemoved(Element child, int oldLogicalIndex)`. Now I can get the notification in index added method.

But when I change the Xamarin.Forms 4.7 version, it shows exception for `OnChildRemoved(Element child, int oldLogicalIndex)` unavailability.

How to resolve this?

I need to use Xamarin.Forms 4.5 and 4.8 both version.

Comment: How can you use Xamarin.Forms 4.5 and 4.8 both version at the same time?

Comment: I need to deliver custom layout to my user. So, my user already using 4.5 version. Now reported issue in 4.8 version. I need to resolve this problem in both version. I can't restrict the version in my user.

Comment: Since Xamarin is always going into a lot of changes, new issues, new features, resolved issues upon any release, in my humble opinion it is better and a lot easier now and in future for you and your client to use the same xf version.

Comment: If a user use 4.5 version, then you can make it work by `OnChildRemoved(Element child)`. While if a user use 4.8 version,  you can make it work by `OnChildRemoved(Element child, int oldLogicalIndex)`. They are two different apps and I don't understand where is the problem.